# No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed

Tags: c++, debugging, opencv, visual-studio-2005

please can anybody help me? I'm suffering - every time I debug my c++ (opencv) code, I have an exception and then the following msg:

> No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed.

What's the matter, and how can I solve it? my colleagues have executed the same code but had no errors or exceptions.

I am running Windows 7 32 bit and Visual Studio 2005, opencv 2.2.0

Comment: Read a bit more your compiler and debugger documentations.

Comment: sorry but where can i find that?

Comment: You should check what line of code causes the error. You will not have symbols if its in an external library, so getting an idea where it happens helps a lot.

Comment: i used opencv library only and i connect it with visual studio for me and for my partner, the same copy of opencv, VS, in the same way, and the same code she has no errors and i have the previous error. so i guess it's not code error , right?

Comment: Well, most likely its caused by different runtime versions. But you really should step into your project and check out where the error happens.

Comment: i had an exception at this statement 
"IplImage* hsv = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(Img), 8, 3 );"

is there is a solution?

Comment: @NermeenoAlami Any reason in particular you're using `IplImage` and not `Mat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem has been solved... It was a problem with an image path.

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP's issue has been solved, there is another possibility for this error that I have come across (might help someone else).

You can check under Debug->Exceptions; if any of the exceptions in this window are checked, it may show that popup if you come across a First Chance Exception.  None of these need to be checked to simply debug your code, but are helpful if you're trying to track down a particular exception.